# hub pull-request to compare and pull-request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Is this command:

```
hub pull-request --base OWNER:master --head MYUSER:my-branch
```

the same as

```
git push origin <MY_BRANCH>
```

and already compared and pull request on the repo of master?

I just want to make sure if it is not pushed to at `Master` because it would be really fatal if I do.

I'm tired of pushing by command origin mybranch and then opening GitHub again to compare & pull the request so I want to find out about the shorthand method.

Is the command I gave a way to push and pull request without performing a push at master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`hub pull-request` command](https://hub.github.com/hub-pull-request.1.html) creates a pull request, so it will not "push to master".

You need to add the `--push` option in order to push the current branch to HEAD before creating the pull request.

Or: push your branch yourself, then try `hub pull-request`, that way you are sure there is no unintentional push.